# Change css of iframe using jquery not working (same domain)

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, jsfiddle

I've looked and tested tonnes of examples of how you can manipulate the contents of an iframe from the parent. However on trying it for myself I cannot get it to work - neither in my test environment (which is all on the same domain, and url) nor on jsfiddle:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/3x6mncxf/

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: your code is good, in your fiddle change "Frameworks & Extensions" option from 'onLoad' to 'onDomReady' see the updated fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/3x6mncxf/4/

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is just change the code a bit. 
Instead of load() method use ready() method

```
 $('iframe#frame').ready( function() {
      $('iframe#frame').contents().find("head").append($("<style type='text/css'>  body{display:none;}  </style>"));
 });
```

I've forked the jsfiddle of yours you can see the demo [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/2pesfysm/)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your jsfiddle, you should use ready() instead of load(), which has been deprecated since v1.8 of JQuery.  This code should work:

```
$('iframe#frame').load( function() {
    $('iframe#frame').contents().find("head").append($("<style type='text/css'>  body{display:none;}  </style>"));
});
```

Alternatively, if you wish to only hide one element, you can always use css().

```
$('iframe#frame').contents().find("body").css("display","none");
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I should have been more specific though in that I am actually trying to insert a lot of css styling. I was just using the body display:none as a quick and dirty test.

Comment: Ah, I think I found the problem.  Use ready() instead of load().  I validated it on your jsfiddle and it worked.  load() has been deprecated since v1.8.

Answer (score 1):

based on recommendation from http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Try using "ready" instead of "load"

```
$('iframe#frame').ready( function() { $('iframe#frame').contents().find("head").append($("<style type='text/css'>  body{display:none;}  </style>"));});
```

It's working fine. except for a fraction of seconds I could see the contents from iframe